# How to Write Solr Plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, solr

I'm trying write plugin to Solr that during indexing will change values of fields 
for example

```
<str name="user">w34m;adam</str> on <str name="greeting">adam</str>
```

but I don't known which Classes to use and generally.How to do it? Can anyone by at help?

Answer (score 1):

By extending [UpdateHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#UpdateHandler) class in Solr you can make changes in the indexing algorithm.

Also check [SolrPlugins](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins) page for other plugin developments.